# React - onClick lost "this"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a material UI table component, and I added a checkout button. 
Everything works fine, except for 2 things which I dont understand :

When `onClick` initializes the `handleCheckout()` function, why    `handleRowSelection()` and `isSelected()` is fired as well?

Most important, when `onClick` calls `handleCheckout()` , it losses the context of `this` , and shows me that `this.state.selected is []`.

```
export default class PredictionsTable extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        selected: [],
        tableData: [],
        checkout: false
    }
}


componentWillMount(){
    axios.get('/dashboard')
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                tableData: response.data,
            });
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

isSelected = (index) => {
    return this.state.selected.indexOf(index) !== -1;
};

handleCheckout = (event) => {
```

Here "this" is lost , and it does not show the updated state of selected

```
   console.log(this.state.selected);
};

handleRowSelection = (selectedRows) => {
    this.setState({
            selected: selectedRows,
        },function(){
    });
};


render() {
    return (
        <div className="table">
            <RaisedButton label="Reveal my Forecasts" onClick={this.handleCheckout}
                          labelStyle={{color: greenA700}}
                          buttonStyle={{borderColor: greenA700}}/>
            <Table
                height={"300px"}
                fixedHeader={true}
                fixedFooter={false}
                multiSelectable={true}
                onRowSelection={this.handleRowSelection}
            >
                <TableHeader
                    displaySelectAll={true}
                    adjustForCheckbox={true}
                    enableSelectAll={false}
                >
                    <TableRow style={{background: '#e9eaea'}}>
                        <TableHeaderColumn colSpan="6" style={{textAlign: 'center' , paddingRight: "90px"}}>
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="The forecast coin name">Altcoin Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="The value of the coin according to forecast time">Current
                            Value</TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Upper limit of investment">Profit Sell Order</TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Lower limit of investment">Loss Sell Order</TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Date and time the forecast was generated">Date and
                            time</TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn
                            tooltip="Share information about the forecast">Comments</TableHeaderColumn>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHeader>
                <TableBody
                    showRowHover={true}
                >
                    {this.state.tableData.map((row, index) => (
                        <TableRow key={index} selected={this.isSelected(index)}>
                            <TableRowColumn>{row.coin_name}</TableRowColumn>
                            <TableRowColumn>{row.coin_value}</TableRowColumn>
                            <TableRowColumn style={{paddingLeft: 50}}>{row.profitSellOrder}</TableRowColumn>
                            <TableRowColumn style={{paddingLeft: 50}}>{row.lossSellOrder}</TableRowColumn>
                            <TableRowColumn>{row.ptime}</TableRowColumn>

                            //comments
                            <TableRowColumn>{row.lossSellOrder}</TableRowColumn>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Can you describe a scenario on how you do things?

Comment: The table component has checkbox and an attribute "onRowSelection" which fires handleRowSelection() every time a check box is marked. The handler updates the selected state array . Im trying to fetch all the selected checkbox when the user hits a checkout button without success.

Comment: That is exactly how the function is supposed to work.

Comment: what do u mean?

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor after super();, also bind the methods:

```
this.handleCheckout = this.handleCheckout.bind(this);
```

Comment: This suggestion does not fix the issue :/ I already implemented this with the arrow function.

Comment: this is proper way to go @toni-michel-caubet

Comment: @Kejt I ment elaborate (why), not to repeat the sentence.. haha, anyways, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I did elaborate, but creator deleted post